# Get base uri of io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest

Tags: httprequest, uri, netty

In netty HttpRequest there is only a method request.getUri() which returns the path after host:port. Is there any way I can get the entire url, or the host:port values separately?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to construct this from the channel via the `Channel.localAddress()` on the server-side.

Comment: Is it possible to see the protocol anywhere? i.e.: `http://` or `wss://` or `ws://` or `https://`

Comment: no... what you can do is check if the `SslHandler` / `WebSocketDecoder` is in the pipeline and based on this make assumptions about the protocol

Comment: Thanks Norman, and thanks for all your work on Netty!!! I got that working, I also found that I can just check for the existence of `Upgrade=websocket` HTTP header to know if it's websocket upgrade request or not. (`ws://` vs `http://`)